# Leave input with value 0 ( PHP, MySql)

Tags: php, mysql, web, input

I want to show the students' grades. This is what I have in `prueba.php`

[image: Image of web browser]

And I have this on my table qualifications in my database:
[image: Image of Database]

How can I leave students who do not qualifications with an input value of 0?

This is my code of prueba.php

```
    <table>
    <tbody>
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root", "");
if (!$connect) {
die(mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("liceo");
$results = mysql_query("SELECT rut, nombre, apellido FROM alumnos") or die(mysql_error);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($results)) {
$rut = $row->rut;

$results2 = mysql_query("SELECT nota FROM notas WHERE rut_alumno = '$rut' LIMIT 1");
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$row->rut?></td>
<td><?=$row->nombre?></td>
<td><?=$row->apellido?></td>
<td>

<?php
while($nota = mysql_fetch_object($results2)):
?>
<input type="text" name="pin" maxlength="2" size="2" value="<?=$nota->nota?>">
<?php
endwhile;
?>
</td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: first of all don't use deprecated `mysql_*` library. use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. Second Use `JOIN`  query to get the output in single query. Third check that  qualification value is not empty. if yes then add 0 manually in your code

Comment: @AlivetoDie Thanks, but how i check that qualification value is not empty for add 0 in the input value?

Comment: trough if condition after fetching record and iterating on that

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: See about JOINs. Then see about LEFT JOINs.